# sendmailR: html and multilingual support

Tags: html, r, email, multilingual

I use sendmailR (ver. 1.0-0) to create automated corporate mails. Inside the mail message I insert html code to produce tables. Finally, before sending, I convert the message to utf8 - since it contains multilingual characters, using

```
msg <- iconv(msg, to = "utf8")
```

After migrating to ver. 1.1-2 (in order to send mails with attachments), the contents of the mail cannot be read anymore. The text is unreadable and the html code is ignored. This is an example of the contents after upgrading:

```
Î³Î¹Î± Ï„Î¿ Î¼Î®Î½Î± Î”ÎµÎºÎ­Î¼Î²Ï Î¹Î¿ (Î±Î½Î¬ ÏƒÏ Î¼Î²Î±ÏƒÎ· ÎºÎ±Î¹ Î±Î¸Ï Î¿Î¹ÏƒÏ„Î¹ÎºÎ¬), Î­Ï‡Î¿Ï…Î½ Ï‰Ï‚ ÎµÎ¾Î®Ï‚.<br><br> <b>Î‘Î½Î¬ ÎšÎ±Ï„Î·Î³Î¿Ï Î¯Î± ÎºÎ±Î¹ Î£Ï Î¼Î²Î±ÏƒÎ·</b><br>

  <table style='border-collapse: collapse; border-color: rgb(136, 136, 136); border-width: 1px;' border='1' bordercolor='#888888' cellspacing='0'>

  <tbody><tr>

  <td style='text-align: center; width: 40px; height: 20px;'>&nbsp;Î‘.A.</td>
```

Do you suggest to continue using the initial version?

Thank you